# iPhone - how to create a Textured Background

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, background, textures

In the Interface Builder (xCode/Mac) I would like to set a Textured Background color. How can I add a texture (image) so I'll be able to use a new custom background?

I know I can set the background like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bg.png"]];
}
```

How can I do this with the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your own UIImage's as a background pattern in Interface Builder but you can use the ones built in

[image]
[image]